# Getting list of column classes for all ffdf columns

Tags: r, dataframe, ff

I have a ffdf with several columns.  I would like to find the column classes that read.table.ffdf automatically determined from the data as a vector of strings.

A crude way of doing this seems to be looping over the columns and using class(Data[1,index]).  Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this all at once?

I tried looking at the methods of the ffdf object, but none seem appropriate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple to do. You are looking for the virtual storage mode of the ffdf.

Try the following:

```
vmode.ffdf(Data)
```